# BASH: How to store commands with variables into a new variable?

Tags: bash

I want to store the ith line of a file (filename stored in variable filename) into a new variable called line where:

```
filename=$2
i=$1
```

let's say for this sake i=1 and filename=names.txt):

```
line="$(sed '1q;d' names.txt)"
```

How would I store the actual filename and i variable?

Comment: does this work also for the sed example? ie sed '$iq:d' $filename)" because I get an error for the $i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
line=$(sed "${i}q;d" $filename)
```

For example,

```
$filename="a.txt"

i=1

line=$(sed "${i}q;d" $filename)

echo $line 
aaa
```

a.txt like this:

```
aaa
bbb
```

The key is that you need double quotes for `${i}` otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: Hmm that gives me an error..however that is the output I want

Comment: the 1q;d must be in single quotes? not sure if that affects it. ie must be sed '1q;d' names.txt

Comment: what environment do you have? what kind of error do you get?